# GWT maven project compiles and run from maven but don't compile and run in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-2.7

I have multi module maven project, that is build with gwt as a main web framework. [Here is github repo.](https://github.com/masterdany88/gwt_2.7.0_maven_eclipse)

Everythink works as it should as I supose. I haven't got anything wrong.

Unfortunatelly the problems occur when I try to import this project into eclipse (as maven project). I can not compile this project (*using RMB on project in Package Explorer -> Google -> GWT Compile*).

I am getting an error:

```
Loading inherited module 'src.main.resources.pl.derp.parent'
   Loading inherited module 'pl.derp.shared'
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'pl/derp/shared.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

When I tried to *RMB on Project name in Package Explorer -> Run -> Run as Web application (GWT Super Dev Mode)*
I've got:

```
Working directory does not exist: /home/danielo/eclipseGwt/gwt_2.7.0_maven_eclipse/web/src/main/webapp
```

I've added modules to build path.

I've followed this [instruction](http://xebee.xebia.in/index.php/2013/06/16/import-and-run-gwt-maven-project-in-eclipse/)

I think, that I've done everything to make it work, but still can make it work.

I think the problem is in packages name, and the way they are treated by maven and eclipse. They are treated in diferent ways.

Maven easily find every class (f.e.: `package pl.derp.web;`) needed and compile. The eclipse is trying to find them by f.e.: `src.main.java.pl.derp.web` but can't found it.

Really I don't know how to resolve this issue?
I am not sure witch package name patter is better (`src.main.java.pl.derp.server` or `pl.derp.server`)- for me the shorter is better.

To run this project in maven (it is well described [here](https://github.com/masterdany88/gwt_2.7.0_maven_eclipse/blob/master/README.md)):

- mvn clean install
- mvn tomcat7:run-war-only

and in second shell:

- mvn gwt:run -pl web

And in Eclipse I think I am running built in `Jetty server`

Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently have a single Eclipse project, with `server`, `shared`, and `web` declared as source directories. When using M2Eclipse, you should have 3 projects, each with their `src/{main,test}/{java,resources}` declared as  source directories. At a minimum, without M2Eclipse, the source directories must be the `src/{main,test}/{java,resources}`, whether you have 1 or 3 projects.

This is why Eclipse looks for `src.main.java.pl.derp.server` instead of `pl.derp.server`, and why GWT fails too (classpath is similarly wrong).

Comment: Ok. I've fixed it. I use short package names like: `pl.der.web`. But when I tried to compile it using eclipse, I am getting an error: `[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor `
...
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor`. I don't have any error in Eclipse IDE. Still using maven it compiles without any error. How should I compile my project? Can I set up in maven compilation output style?